# Multiple conditions on data set, obtaining original row numbers in R

Tags: r

My problem is that I have a bunch of nodes, that internally save row numbers of a main set x.

Let's say I want to split data of the set x into two new nodes, but of course this data can only be put into a child node if it already exists in the parent.

To illustrate

```
# obtain the right data from x, using your saved rowNumbers
parentData <- x[parentNode$rowNumbers, ]

# take out the rows that meet some condition based on a column value
filter <- parentData[, someColumnNumber] > someCondition

# now we obtain the actual rownames based on x
childNode$rowNumbers <- rownames(parentData[filter, ])
```

Is there a prettier way to do this? Above code works, but I've also been looking at `which()`, but the problem is that if you condition on both the row number and the extra column constraint, you just build a new data.frame with less rows than x. If you use `which()` on this new data.frame, you'll just get indices starting at 1 again instead of the indices you want to use from your parent node.

Edit:

Here's a more clear example of what I mean.

Here is the dummy data

```
x <- structure(list(class = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), splittingHere = 28:32, 
    anotherColumn = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 4L)), .Names = c("class", 
"splittingHere", "anotherColumn"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Now imagine parentData has saved inside, due to an earlier split on some column, that it contains row 1, 2 and 4. So

```
rowNumbers <- c(1,2,4)
parentData <- x[rowNumbers, ]
```

We have to send some values to our child depending on the condition, lets say > 30

```
filter <- parentData[ , 2 ] > 30
```

Now what I want are the row numbers that meet this condition. If I do

```
which(filter)
```

It just gives me 3, because it's the third element of this vector that is true. But its not the third in x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....Okay while testing the example I solved it.

Solution is obviously just

```
rowNumbers[filter]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do most of this with logical vectors without having to subset the whole data.frame multiple times (potentially slow if you've got a big df and aren't using data.table.

What about something like this?

```
selWch <- which( parentData[ , someColumnNumber ] > someCondition )

selAll <- selWch[ selWch %in% rowNumbers ]
```

Which returns the row numbers from the full data.frame, then you check if those row numbers match your index of rowNumbers you want to further subset on using `%in%`.

Comment: The problem with that though is that, lets say 
`parentData[, someColumnNumber] > someCondition` returns row 1, 2 and 10 of the original data set x
then `selWch` will be set to 1, 2 and 3, right?
so then `selWch[selWch %in% rowNumbers]` returns 1 and 2...but not 10

Comment: @Frank Nope.  The logical comparison returns a logical vector of the same length as the longest vector being compared (they're the same length here).  So the `which` turns that into `c(1,2,10)`.  As with most things, a fully reproducible example (make a dummy data.frame and `dput` it) would aid understanding as well as get you better answers.

Comment: While creating a dummy example I solved it...thanks for the help, I edited it in for people who struggle with something alike.

Comment: @Frank Ah it's more clear what you want now.  And not surprised you solved it while creating the dummy example--that's half the reason to create them!

Comment: @Frank That said, you should post your answer as an answer rather than in the question itself.